# Is it possible to set a fixed position for Web Controller Tooltip in ASP.Net?

Tags: c#, javascript, css, asp.net, tooltip

I am having an `ImageButton` with `Tooltip` as shown below,

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="btnDEmail" ImageUrl="~/Images/email.png" 
     runat="server" Height="100px" ToolTip="Email" 
     BorderColor="Black" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px" 
     OnClick="Email_Click" />
```

When I try to hover on the `ImageButton` the tooltip shows on random places near the pointer. Is it possible to display the `tooltip` on the right side of button or in any place other than popping on the image button?

Comment: You can't style the title, you would have to use a javascript tooltip plugin instead

Answer (score 0):

No, its not. The Tooltip property, turns actually into the `title` property of the `<img>` element. The title property's show event is handled by the browser, not subject to manipulation.

You would have to build (or find) a custom tooltip for your element.